# Check for dialogs(created from async task) in espresso

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-espresso

In my app, I press login button and it makes a server call to download user data using an async task, and I show the progress(with couple additional data) using a custom dialog from the async task.

I want to test this scenario using espresso. Basically what I wanna do is press the login button(which is the simplest part of it) and then as async task runs and the custom dialog is updated, I wanna check the data of the dialog(match the text that is displayed).

Sort of something like below:

```
onView(withId(R.id.login_button))
                .perform(click());
onView(withText("Data 1"))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed())); // This is displayed by the async task while it runs.
onView(withText("Data 2"))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed())); // Again updated by async task while it runs.
```

I know that when we perform an action(pressing the login button here), espresso will run everything on the main thread and it won't let me do anything else(like check if dialog is shown) until the app becomes idle(i.e. async task is finished). Espresso will only run my actions, when it finds that the app is not doing anything(but till then dialogs will be gone).

This may sound like working against what espresso lets you do. But this is actually what I have to test.

As of now, I have no clue on how to achieve it, and waiting for any help on this problem.